# perl fast json parser program

Tags: json, performance, perl

My JSON file contains some 3000 lines of content like below:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "number":"111",
                    "price":"3170",
                    "stock":"1"
                },
                {
                    "number":"222",
                    "price":"3170",
                    "stock":"1"
                },
                {
                    "number":"333",
                    "price":"3749",
                    "stock":"1"
                }
            ],
            "object":"apple",
            "id":"54529"
        },
        {
            "data":[],
            "object":"orange",
            "id":"54524"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to parse them really quick.

Below is my code. It's not working ..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( );

my $filename = 'mob.json';

my $json_text = do
{
   open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename);
   local $/;
   <$json_fh>
};

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

for ( @{$data->{'product'}} )
{
    print $_->{data}[0]->{number};
}
```

I need to get the `number`, `price`, `stock` and `object`, `id` as well.

Comment: There are many many ways in which code can be said to be not working. In what particular way is your code not working?

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value in print at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scripts\jsonfile.pl line 20.
111`
this is what i get...and it stops there.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm#SPEED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. Almost. I made a couple of tweaks.

You alluded to speed at the beginning. Not clear if you wanted a quick answer, or a quicker way to parse lots of information. If it's the former, read on. If it's the latter, make sure you have JSON::XS installed.

Style-wise I find it painful to look at.

1. The use of a `do{}` to read the file makes me want to hurt myself. But, you used 3-param open. Kudos.
2. You need to deference the array value from the hash
3. You need to handle empty values in the data or you'll keep getting warnings

This code parses your JSON and outputs it, substuting empty vals with 'undefined':

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( );

my $filename = 'mob.json';

my $json_text = do {
   open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename);
   local $/;
   <$json_fh>;
};

my $json = JSON->new()->utf8(1);
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

for my $product ( @{$data->{'product'}} ){

    my ($name, $id) = map { $product->{$_} // 'undefined' } qw(name id);
    print sprintf("Product: %s (%s)\n", $name, $id);

    foreach my $data ( @{$product->{'data'}} ) {
        my ($number, $price, $stock) =
            map { $data->{$_}//'undefined' } qw(number price stock);

        print sprintf(
            "    number: %s, price: %s, stock: %s\n",
            $number,
            $price,
            $stock,
        );
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey David, Thanks.. This is what I wanted.

Comment: If we’re going over style points: `print sprintf`??? `()` is fewer characters than `qw( )`, same with `for` v `foreach`. :P